# Page temporarily unavailable - NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have an issue which I suspect is an NGINX problem. Basically when I try to log on to the site I created I get the folowing error......

**the page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. please try again later.**

Has anyone ever come across this before?

Answer (score 3):

This problem may occur if you have incorrect `fastcgi_pass` directive in NGINX vhost file.

If you use fastcgi, it should be similar to this: `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

If you use fpm, it should be like this: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

P.S. It is a one year old question, but Google directs me to this question for this problem. So I decided to write what I found.

Answer (score 2):

Does your site using FastCGI? This message could be returned because [the FastCGI server is not running](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx#Error%3a_The_page_you_are_looking_for_is_temporarily_unavailable._Please_try_again_later.).

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to get rid of error on symfony and this vagrant image https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev this nginx config:

```
server {
 listen [::]:80;
 listen 80;

 server_name test;

 root /var/www/default/web;

 charset utf-8;

 index index.php index.html;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 client_max_body_size 128M;
 location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

 location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
   include fastcgi_params;

   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
 }

 location / {
   try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
 }
}
```

You need to adjust root, server_name to match your case.